# Sentry not showing source map for Error in Next.js project deployed on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, sentry

I have a Next.js project deployed on Vercel.
I have completed the integration of Sentry with Vercel as mentioned here in docs : https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/deployment/vercel/

But when I see an error on Sentry, the stack trace looks something like this. Which isn't readable and understandable.

[image]

I can see my latest deployment in Releases on Sentry. And in release details, I can also see the source maps created.

[image]

I investigated further using `sentry-cli` using command `sentry-cli sourcemaps explain a7bdb2613968438f99917e71f9903606`, but got an error **"Uploaded artifacts do not include entry: ~/_next/static/chunks/pages/play-b473d401c0214fd2.js"**

[image]

Anyone has any idea why the error stack trace is still showing trace using minified files  instead of source maps ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/troubleshooting_js/

Comment: @JBallin edited to Q to include response from sentry-cli. Error: uploaded artifacts do not include entry ....

Comment: I have this problem too. click in source maps link in release page and check there is any .../static/chunks... or all of them are  ../server/...